# SLI Artifact issues

Tags: gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, sli

When I enable SLI I keep getting artifacts in random games and in Windows Aero sometimes .

It doesn't seem to be about over-heating as it happens randomly, and sometimes whole computers just crashes (not blue-screen, just black gone...)

My setup:

- Geforce 8800 GTS 320MB ( http://www.bfgtech.com/bfgr88512gtoce.aspx ) x 2
- GIGABYTE EX58-UD4
- Windows 7 RC
- PSU 800W

I've got the latest NVIDIA drivers and F5 BIOS update (*SLI update*).
When I disable SLI and use the cards separately they are working just fine even in games.

Any idea why this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a non-RC version of a Windows OS to try? nVidia doesn't officially support Windows 7 RC, so there's no ruling out the drivers as an issue until you're on a supported OS.